# Find longest even value path in binary tree, return length of said path, non-recursive

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I have to create an algorithm to find the longest path of even value in a binary tree without using recursion.
For example, if my tree is the following:
[Binary Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvQmc.png)

The algorithm should return `3` as that is the length of the longest path of only even value.

Requirements:

- We have two queues we can use
- The path must start from the root(which we are given)

What I have in mind as of now:

- Use `Morris Traversal` to go over the tree, but I don't know in which part of the code to do the "path search" portion
- Somehow, use the queues to save the relevant nodes, `q1` would represent the `tempLongestPath` and another one that is `overallLongestPath.`

But I don't have a clear idea about saving the path's length while going over the tree.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: shouldn't the answer be 4 (4->8->2->10->4)

Comment: No, since it has to be from the root(which we are given), my apologies for not adding that to the question.

Comment: For Morris Traversal you need to modify the tree which might break the solution path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a BFS, pretend only even values are in the tree and keep track of the length.

Pseudocode:

```
queue.put(root)
L[root] = 1
Max_L = -1
while !Queue.empty():
   current = queue.pull()
   if (current %2 ==1): SKIP/CONTINUE

   if Max_L < L[current]:
       Max_L = L[current]
   if current.left:
      queue.put(current.left)
      L[current.left] = L[current]+1
   if current.right:
      queue.put(current.right)
      L[current.right] = L[current]+1
return Max_L
```

If you don't want to use an array or something sensible (i.e. dictionary) to store the lengths, you can use the second queue to keep track of them (do a put instead of assigning to L and do a pull when you pull from `queue`)

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking the time to answer; I appreciate it.
I just wanted to clarify what `L` refers to and what `Max_L` refers to.

Comment: `L` is what we use to store the even-path Length to each node. `Max_L` is Maximum Length that the algorithm is going to return.

Comment: Assuming we want to use the `queue` to store the path length, what changes would be made to the pseudocode?
One limitation is that I need to use `constant memory,` and I think the `L` solution would make it dynamic memory.
How would this part work if it was a `queue`:
```if Max_L < L[current]:```

Comment: you can use the second queue instead of `L` to store the current length. Like instead of `L[root] = 1` you can write `queue_L.put(1)` and instead of using `L[current]` you can do `current_len = queue_L.pull()` and then use `current_len` to compare like `if Max_L < current_len:`, While updating `L[current.left] = L[current] +1` you can do `queue_L.put(current_len+1)`.

Comment: and what made you think queue does not require dynamic memory?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out with the changes.
I guess I hadn't thought about it, but yeah, it uses dynamic memory, maybe because the task put "constant memory" as a limitation.